# How can I pass e-mail with Oauth MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

I'm using code from this tutorial (of course, not all). Everything works perfectly, but when I tried to pass email, I have `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException`. Why? How can I pass e-mail value from Facebook?

```
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { 
                UserName = result.UserName, 
                ExternalLoginData = loginData,
                FullName = result.ExtraData["name"],
                Email = result.ExtraData["email"],
                ProfileLink = result.ExtraData["link"],
            });
```

This works:

```
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { 
                UserName = result.UserName, 
                ExternalLoginData = loginData,
                FullName = result.ExtraData["name"],
                //Email = result.ExtraData["email"],
                ProfileLink = result.ExtraData["link"],
            });
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't share Email addresses by default.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12883880/65716) for more information, but you can change your registration model to require email when making a user registration for your site.  Also, you can check that the collection has the key first, before trying to access it

```cs
AuthenticationResult result =
    OAuthWebSecurity
        .VerifyAuthentication(
            Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));

// Log in code

if (result.ExtraData.ContainsKey("email"))
    // Use email
```